# Updating called data within ajax embedded php pages via mysql(no errors appearing)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html, forms

so I am attempting to have a page where via a drop down menu populated from a database(working) It calls up the desired data set to be modified.  I have sql injection protection already implemented, the drop down menu populates and the desired dataset is displayed.  I how ever can not figure out how to submit data that has been changed.  There is no error that appears, nothing appears to happen.  I have checked within the database to ensure that the data values were not in fact being changed and they were not.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

table8.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
if (str=="") {
document.getElementById("txtDisp").innerHTML="";
return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
document.getElementById("txtDisp").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser3.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="localhost/table8.php">
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['uname'] . "</option>";
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtDisp"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

getuser3.php

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . $q . "";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Username</th><th>E-Mail</th><th>Info 1</th></tr>";

echo "<form action=\"localhost/insertgetuser.php\" method=\"post\">";

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"uname\" value=" . $row1['uname'] . "></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row1['email'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row1['info1'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "<input type=\"submit\">";
echo "</form>";

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

insertgetuser.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['uname']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$info1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['info1']);


$sql="UPDATE INTO users (uname, email, info1)
VALUES ('$uname', '$email', '$info1')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="localhost/insertgetuser.php">
```

Does not look right, probably you want to post to `instertgetuser.php` (i doubt the localhost part is needed):

```
<form method="post" action="insertgetuser.php">
```

Comment: negative, I just tried and this does not work.  I still end up with no response when I click submit.  Also if you are referring to changing up the post on table8.php and not getuser3.php, it is required to post to itself for the drop down menu selection to work to display the dataset within getuser3.php

Comment: Yes i edited my answer when i spotted that mistake. However i dont see how you can have "no response" with the form produced by getuser3.php as it is a standard form that should cause a page refresh no matter whether the data in it is correct, unless you have some javascript preventing the form submitting?